# f:ajax listener fails within dynamically added h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm dynamically adding a `h:selectOneMenu` to the page. But the `listener` method for `f:ajax` is not invoked for selectItems but it does work if `h:selectOneMenu` had been added to the page from the start (not dynamically added using `update` attribute).
My code as follows:

(Corrected after @Daniel's suggestion)

```
    <h:commandButton value="Watch">
          <f:ajax render="deptsSelBox"/>
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{listRetriever.allow}" />
    </h:commandButton>  

    <h:panelGroup id="deptsSelBox">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="deptsSel" rendered="#{listRetriever.allow}" value="#{listRetriever.reqId}">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{listRetriever.list}" />
            <f:ajax listener="#{listRetriever.retrieve()}" execute="deptsSel" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h:commandButton` got no `update` attribute, Looks like a mix of primefaces and pure JSF (`update` attribute is from `p:commandButton`)

Add `f:ajax` to your `commandButton` and use `render` attribute

```
<h:commandButton value="Watch">
      <f:ajax render="deptsSelBox"/>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{listRetriever.allow}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

also fix your selection ajax to this

```
<f:ajax listener="#{listRetriever.retrieve}" update="deptsSel"/>
```

and try change scope from `request` to `view`

another approach would be to set the value of `allow` inside a method , like this (you can also send it as a parameter too)

```
<h:commandButton value="Watch" action="listRetriever.updateAllow">
      <f:ajax render="deptsSelBox"/>
</h:commandButton>  


public void updateAllow(){
     allow = true;
}
```

Comment: yes were correct I was using primefaces, however even after correcting  this,  f:ajax(2nd one) still fails for the dynamically added `h:selectOneMenu`. Please note that the `h:selectOneMenu` is successfully added to the page, however the f:ajax doesnt still work for the selectItems.

Comment: updated my answer , <f:ajax listener="#{listRetriever.retrieve}" update="deptsSelBox" />
also post your retrieve code

Comment: Regarding your suggestion for selection `f:ajax`, I cannot update  `deptsSelBox` again since the bean is no longer available it was just request scoped & was erased soon after the selectOneMenu had been rendered. Btw why do I need to update `deptSelBox` again !?

Comment: since you haven't posted any java code i guessed that `listRetriever.list` might been manipulated so to be on the safe side i guessed you better reload it by reloading its wrapper (not sure its needed...)

Comment: yes `listRetriever.list` is manipulated for some uses later, but I believe there should be no need for this once the selectitems have been rendered on the page, isnt it ?

Comment: i think you should try to update `deptsSel` like this (unless it works for you without the update , )`<f:ajax listener="#{listRetriever.retrieve}" update="deptsSel"/>` (not sure)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. will try this out.. but when I directly added the selectOneMenu to the page from start instead of adding dynamically later, f:ajax worked properly without using the `update` within it.

Comment: Thanks it works with Viewscope but I dont understand why it needs access to the list later for ajax operations after once initially rendering onto the page.

Comment: I guess its cause you are modifying it later on with the retrieve (although I don't see the entire picture here, I'd guess you better fill the drop down list from post constructor.... )